# Why non closed differential forms do not play important role for the topology of a manifold?

Tags: differential-topology, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

The question may seems very obvious but I don't know the answer right now. I know that De Rham cohomology reveal some properties of the topology of smooth manifolds by finding closed differential $k$-forms $\mathsf{d}\omega=0$ that are not exact $\omega\neq\mathsf{d}\eta$. I wonder

> **Question:** Why non closed differential forms do not play important role for the topology of a manifold?

One can say that because the closed forms work pretty well i.e.  the PDE approach to closed and exact forms that asks for solvability of a system of differential equations, then Poincare Lemma enters. All goal of the solvability is based on closedness and exactness of system of differential equations. The other reason is that the set of all non-closed forms, is not a vector space. But these are not a good and convincing reason for  non-closed forms not affecting on the topology of the manifold.

Comment: The answer to this question surely is that they actually do. I do not know the details, so I can't give you a complete answer, but if I recall correctly, there is a theory going back to Sullivan that (probably with some small caveats I'm forgetting) derives the real homotopy type of a smooth manifold from its algebra of differential forms.

Comment: What would the alternative be? Taking the quotient gives something of generally finite dimension that furthermore is a homotopy invariant. The cohomology does not tell you everything about the topology, it is just one invariant that is easy to compute.

Comment: Qualitatively speaking, we often want to know about the *global* topological features of a manifold, since their local features are just inherited from $\mathbb{R}^n$. The algebra of differential forms, however, contains lots of superfluous information relating to these local features. Restricting attention to closed forms and cohomology classes is an efficient way to discard this extra information.

Comment: Re @Thorgott's comment, [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461484677) is the relevant reference. In a word (well a few), Postnikov towers and spectral sequences are showing up, and with those spectral sequences, non-closed differential forms.

Comment: How would you know that two different closed forms were in the same cohomology class, were it not for the existence of a very conveniently behaved non-closed form?

Comment: @LeeMosher: Do you meant $\alpha -\beta =d\psi\iff [\alpha]=[\beta]$?

Comment: Well, it should really be $(\exists \psi$ such that  $\alpha - \beta = d \psi) \iff [\alpha]=[\beta]$, but yeah.

Comment: @Thorgott: From its graded  algebra of differential forms? OK, how can one sure that the properties that that real homotopy type derived from graded  algebra of differential forms cannot be derived just by closed forms? you meant "graded  algebra of **all** differential forms" and not just non-closed one.